# Create a calculated Column for is previous month based on one column in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

```
CUSTNAME    DATE         SALES
  AAAA     2022-12-31      30
  BBBB     2022-12-31      40
  AAAA     2023-01-31      50
  BBBB     2023-01-31      60
  AAAA     2023-02-28      70
  BBBB     2023-02-28      80
```

above is my sample table and now I want to create one calculated column which will have pervious month data based on CUSTNAME column. I need to get below desired output.

```
CUSTNAME    DATE         SALES  PERMDATA
  AAAA     2022-12-31      30    NULL
  BBBB     2022-12-31      40    NULL
  AAAA     2023-01-31      50     30
  BBBB     2023-01-31      60     40
  AAAA     2023-02-28      70     50
  BBBB     2023-02-28      80     60
```

please help me on this.

Comment: In accordance with the general rules of this forum, please edit your question to show what you have tried, and exactly where you need assistance. Also, please clarify if you are looking for a solution in Power BI (DAX) or Power Query, since you have tagged both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of ways in M

Merge on top of self. Probably fastest for large dataset:

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Index",{{"CUSTNAME", type text}, {"DATE", type date}, {"SALES", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "LASTDATE", each Date.AddDays(Date.StartOfMonth([DATE]),-1)),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom", {"CUSTNAME", "LASTDATE"}, #"Added Custom", {"CUSTNAME", "DATE"}, "Added Custom", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Added Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Added Custom", {"SALES"}, {"PERMDATA"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Added Custom",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index", "LASTDATE"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

Custom column pulling a match for each row. Smallest. Slowest:

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"CUSTNAME", type text}, {"DATE", type date}, {"SALES", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","PERMDATA",(x)=>try Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each  [CUSTNAME]=x[CUSTNAME] and [DATE]=Date.AddDays(Date.StartOfMonth(x[DATE]),-1)) [SALES]{0} otherwise null ,type number)
in  #"Added Custom"
```

Group and shift row. Probably between the two in terms of speed:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"DATE", type date}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"CUSTNAME"}, {{"data", each 
    let a = Table.Sort(_,{{"DATE", Order.Ascending}}),
    shiftedList = {null} & List.RemoveLastN(a[SALES],1),
    custom1 = Table.ToColumns(a) & {shiftedList}
    in Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(a) & {"PERMDATA"})
, type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"DATE", "SALES", "PERMDATA","Index"}, {"DATE", "SALES", "PERMDATA","Index"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded data",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution based on DAX:

```
PreviousMonthSales = CALCULATE(SUM(YourTableName[Sales]),PREVIOUSMONTH(YourTableName[Date]))
```